# Attaching Event Handlers after Infinite Scroll Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am using the infinite scroll plugin http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/ to load page content.

I have a jQuery event listener such as:

```
$('.like-action').on('click',
    function(event){
      likeComment($(this)); 
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

That get's loaded on `$(document).ready`. However, when new content is loaded with the `infinitescroll` the event listeners are not applied/available to the new content. So, I created a function that is called on the callback of the `infinitescroll` (when all content has loaded).The function:

```
function afterUpdate(){
$('.like-action').on('click',function(event){
      likeComment($(this)); 
      event.preventDefault();
});}
```

What ends up happening however, is for the old content (that is already loaded) when a link is clicked that has the `.like-action class`, the `likeComment` function is called however many times new content has been loaded + the original `$(document).ready`.

Ex: content is loaded on page load. link executes `likeComment` 1 on click. After scrolling down and having new content loaded (and callback) if you click the same link as before, `likeComment` is executed twice. etc,etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

Is my event listener written incorrectly?

Is there a way to write a listener that automatically works for all elements in the `DOM` even if they were not there on page load?

Or, is there a way to only register the .on on elements that were just loaded by infinite scroll (so there isn't a duplication)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your usage of `on()` to pass a selector and it will use event delegation, causing the click handlers to work for all future elements as well:

```
$('#someContainer').on('click', '.like-action', function (event){
    likeComment($(this)); 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent your click handlers from ever needing to be added again, solving your issue of them being added multiple times to older elements.

This assumes that all of your current and future `.like-action` elements will be contained inside of `#someContainer`.

Edit: in response to your comment, you cannot delegate plugin initialization like that. what you could do is this: when you initialize an element, add a class to it as well:

```
$('.profilecard').hovercard().addClass('initialized');
```

Then in your callback when you need to initialize the new ones, skip over anything that has that class already:

```
function afterUpdate(){ 
    $('.profilecard:not(".initialized")').hovercard();
}
```

Comment: jbabey, how does this work in regards to something like: `$(document).ready(function() {$( '.profilecard' ).hovercard();});` Since that is not technically attaching an event handler?

Comment: jbabey, just added the change to the .on and it is working like a champ! Thanks! Okay, so the difference between the event handler and adding the plugin initialization is because the plugin is being "attached" to the DOM element? So, the initialized class is used to check if it has been attached?

Comment: [this page](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-use-of-event-delegation/) will help explain why it works for events (`delegate` is the same as `on`, just older). initialization of a plugin doesn't propogate up the DOM like an event so it's not able to be delegated.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in doing this without jQuery, there is a great post here - https://elliotekj.com/2016/11/05/jquery-to-pure-js-event-listeners-on-dynamically-created-elements/

Basic example:

```
document.querySelector(staticParent).addEventListener(eventName, function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains(dynamicChildSelector)) {
    // Do something
  }
})
```

Working example:

```
document.querySelector('.feed').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('feed-item')) {
    // Do something
  }
})
```